# Access Google Analytics without Google Account

Tags: google-analytics

A company is not using Google Suite and it is against company policy to use personal (consumer) accounts (even Google ones).

There is a need to access Google Analytics - is it possible at all without Google Account?

thanks

Comment: Why can't you create a work Google account? If it's a completely separate Google account from your own personal one, and for the purpose of doing your job, how is that against company policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about user access to reports within Google Analytics portal - you have to have Google Account for that. GA does not support federated IDs or ADFS.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009692?hl=en

Accessing data is a different story - your tool (script) can have Google Account to access data, but users of your script, don't have to. Not as robust through. Please have a look at https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

Another option might be to have a "one for all" user account and often change passwords and have a browser extension to automatically log users in - but that really depends on the organization security policy.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Google Analytics without a gmail account, however you must still link your current email to Google's services.

Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount and select "use my current email address instead."

After this, you will have to verify your email, and you can then use this email address to access Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. What you are suggesting is a creation of a Google Account (consumer/personal) one. Unfortunately, we can't do that..

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't sure if you just wanted a way around the Gmail email account. Unfortunately, Google Analytics requires a Google account as far as I'm aware. Fortunately, there are other analytics tools if you need one; check out crazyegg.com and semrush.com for a couple starter examples.